# VBA check if A fits in B but

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure how to explain that so I will just give you straight an example.

I have some strings such as: `123?56` (the `?` means any character). I want to check if a string can fit in another.

Example:

- `123456` fits in `123?56`
- `123B56` fits in `123?56` too.

You get the principle.

Now, there are actually longer strings more like `1234?9ZZ9???72?` and what I want to do is to check if any of the other string present in the column where I have all my data fits in any other string from the same column.

Ideally it would return me every groups of "same numbers", but that part I'm confident I can do it. I just don't know how to approach the `?` char.

The size is rarely more than 4-10K row long.

Comment: `If "123456" Like "123?56" Then`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator

Comment: Check out RegEx. It's very commonly used for this application. https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/

Comment: Like oprator made it. Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very simple code to get you started:

```
Sub CheckStrings()

    Dim string1 As String
    Dim string2 As String
    Dim string3 As String
    Dim string4 As String        

    string1 = "123?56"
    string2 = "123456"
    string3 = "123B56"
    string4 = "notamatch"

    If string2 Like string1 Then
        Cells(1, 1) = "Match"
    Else
        Cells(1, 1) = "No Match"
    End If

    If string3 Like string1 Then
        Cells(1, 2) = "Match"
    Else
        Cells(1, 2) = "No Match"
    End If

    If string4 Like string1 Then
        Cells(1, 3) = "Match"
    Else
        Cells(1, 3) = "No Match"
    End If

End Sub
```

When I run that it puts Match Match No Match into the top corner of my current worksheet.  Hopefully that's enough to adapt to a proper solution?

Comment: Many thanks. How could I not know this operator.


Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer
i = 1: j = 1: count = 2

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To lastrow
count = 2
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value Like Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Cells(i, count).Value = j & "fits in " & i
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub

This made it.